# ics iCal description max length

Tags: php, html, icalendar

I build with php an ics file. the description text has about 1000 characters. Unfortunatly, it caps after 300

ics:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20141002T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=3;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=10
....
LOCATION:Thun
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Basic Overview of PV-Production
DESCRIPTION:Enean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes\, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis\, ultricies nec\, pellentesque eu\, pretium quis\, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo\, fringilla vel\, aliquet nec\, vulputate eget\, arcu. I
```

Code:

```
$ICS_Text = "Enean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cub.";

$ICS_1 = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20141002T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=3;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=10
....
SUMMARY:'.escapeString($kTitel).'
DESCRIPTION:'.$ICS_Text.'
UID:'.md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';
```

Thanks for help.

best regards
thomas

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether your question is around some PHP issue or iCalendar interop issue but, regardless, you definitely have a problem with the later. Your iCalendar stream, as built, is not standard compliant:

Long lines of text (longer than 73 octets actually) should be folded, using the technique described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1

Comment: No examples provided